# EC2 is asking to change password after successful SSH logins

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04

My ec2 machine was running since couple of years and i was able to ssh in that machine using public key, but all of sudden yesterday after successfully logged in through SSH it is asking to change password as password has been expired.
I never set any password expiry policy.

after login screen

[image]

I have deattach the root volume and attached to other instance and checked the password expiry using command `chage -i ununtu` output shows this

[image]

Comment: Try running `chage -M -1 ubuntu`.

Comment: @Arpit Jain ageing is already set to Minimum as 0 and Maximum as 99999 how will this command is going to help?

Comment: i tried it but nothing change

Comment: Maximum:-1 indicates to never expire
Can you try with this : `chage -I -1 -M -1 -E -1 ubuntu`?
-I -1 :  With this => We set: "Password inactive" never.
-E -1 : With this => We set: "Expires Account" never.

Comment: Although, I won't recommend to turn off password expiration from the security point of view.